# how to style father from child with tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am creating a project with nextjs and tailwind css, and I have a problem removing the overflow from the body when I open a modal, the body tag is found in the layout.jsx file and my modal component is found in the page.jsx yes However, I can't find a way to remove the overflow when making my modal component display. I tried to apply the group state style offered by tailwind css, but it doesn't work.

***layout.jsx***

[image]

***page.jsx >> modal component***

[image]

Comment: Might be just a mistake you misspelled group